# How can I autofilter when I'm not sure which column it will be?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to automate the processing of various reports, which I just need to filter and count the rows of. I currently have a PowerShell script that opens each report and runs a few macros. It is just about in a working state, but I'd now like to make it a bit more intelligent and catch some of the fails, so I might be asking a few questions but I'll stick to the one problem on each.

The reports have similar, but not identical layouts. I am looking for a particular column name to then autofilter. I have a very basic and bodged together macro that currently does this, and works (most of the time) for example, sometimes the column I want is A or B:

```
If Worksheets(1).Range("A1") Like "*word" Then
    Worksheets(1).Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=criteria1", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=criteria2"

ElseIf Worksheets(1).Range("B1") Like "*word" Then
    Worksheets(1).Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=criteria", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=criteria2"
```

Hopefully that gives you the current picture.

I now want to instead, do a search for the field header I am looking for, then filter that column, so if the report format in future changes my macro won't break. Something similar to:

```
ColNum = Application.Match("*header", Range("A:Z"), 0)
ColNumInt = CInt(ColNum)

If ColNumInt > 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=ColNumInt, Criteria1:="=criteria1*", Operator:=xlAnd
End If
```

But this gives an error "AutoFilter method of Range class failed", Googlefu says to turn off filters but they're already off. So I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part will always fail:

```
ColNum = Application.Match("*header", Range("A:Z"), 0)
```

since match only works on one row or column. So your code is actually returning Error 2042, which is then converted to 2042 by CInt. I guess you don't have that many columns of data, hence the autofilter fails. Use:

```
ColNum = Application.Match("*header", Range("A1:Z1"), 0)
If Not IsError(ColNum) Then
...
End If
```

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. Out of interest is there a better way to follow errors like this?

Comment: Better in what way? `IsError` will catch any error here.

Comment: Sorry, as in I didn't realise Match was throwing an error and that was the real cause of the filter failing, being passed through the macro. Could that be "handled" better?

Comment: If you use `Application.Match` it returns an error **value** rather than raising a run-time error. If you prefer a run-time error that you can use an error handler to deal with, use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim c As Integer

    Set r = Range("A1:B1").Find(what:="*word*", lookat:=xlWhole)
    c = r.Column
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = 0

    Columns(c).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*criteria1*"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I ran a quick test and this also worked. I marked the previous answer as correct as I was particularly interested in how the error was being converted and passed through, so hopefully that will also help others.